# Where to add firebase config variables on webpack vue project

Tags: firebase, webpack, vue.js, firebase-authentication

Implementing Firebase auth on my Vue webpack project.
Google [tells me to add](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) the config to my index.html file.

If you do this and to go an view page source it exposes the api key to public. I am confused as to why google would suggest this.

Where should I position the configuration variables so it would be safe. [Somebody said](https://medium.com/@anas.mammeri/vue-2-firebase-how-to-build-a-vue-app-with-firebase-authentication-system-in-15-minutes-fdce6f289c3c) that main.js is not a good idea in production.

Where should I do the following in my Vue website.

```
var config = {
   apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
   authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
   projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
   storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: Be informed that in any case your config will be exposed to the public. In the case of a Vue.js project, it will be in one of the js files generated in your project dist folder by webpack when you call `npm run buid`. But this is actually not a problem. There are several posts explaining why it is not a problem that this config is public.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do it in the App.vue

```
import Firebase from 'firebase'
let config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
  };

let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config)
let db = app.database()
let someDataRef = db.ref('dataset')
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean main.js or App.vue cause the image you posted of App.vue?